# What is the difference between fwrite() and file_put_content()?

Tags: php

What is the major difference, as both can be used to write on file. And which one is better for use.

Comment: `fwrite()` allows to write to file a byte or block of bytes at a time, `file_put_content()` writes the entire file in one go.... which is better? depends what you need to do! and on the volumes of data that you want to write!

Comment: `fwrite` requires a handle while `file_put_contents` does not.

Answer (score 5):

"better" depends on your case, if you just want to put content into a file, use `file_put_contents()`, if you need better granularity use `fopen() / fwrite()` where you can write parts, open the file in different modes, navigate with a file-position etc.

Comment: I wish this sentence pops in the php.net manual ; +1 for nice explanation :)